# Scipy Leastsq Optional Output Variable (Mesg)

Tags: python, scipy

SciPy's documentation on LeastSq is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html). It states that `ier` is

> An integer flag. If it is equal to 1, 2, 3 or 4, the solution was found. Otherwise, the solution was not found. In either case, the optional output variable ‘mesg’ gives more information.

But how do I retrieve the optional variable `mesg`?

`x,ier=leastsq(residuals, plsq, args=(x_vals, y_vals))` gives me only two returns while

`x,mesg,ier=leastsq(residuals, plsq, args=(x_vals, y_vals))` gives the error message `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack` on that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [full_output](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) parameter:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
p,cov,infodict,mesg,ier = optimize.leastsq(
    residuals,p_guess,args=(x,y),full_output=True)
```

Comment: Seems that this is not explained in the documentation. I would expect few words like "if `full_output` is set to `True`" in the description of the returns `cov`,`infodict` and `mesg`.